# Single building polygon ("Relation") with 2 building addresses in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

I often see in the "official" map at https://www.openstreetmap.org the following scenario:

[image]

Based on the basics of OSM [Elements](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) I wonder what's going on here?

It seems there are 2 `nodes` on the west side and between them 1 `way`, so I expect this single `way` to hold only 1 `metadata tag`.

When I try to debug it with some OSM data from "geofabrik" I encourage new issue: Ain't building numbers. {This is seems strange to me - Why 1 OSM has this data and other OSM not? I thought it's same data available to all under open source etc.}

Comment: Go to that place (or link it in your question) and in osm web press edit -> With it. So you can see the real nodes, ways and relations.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga Thanks, I checked indeed and it's 2 "hidden" nodes alongside the west line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Openstreetmap, the address information can be  either

- on the building relation
- on a closed way
- on a node representing the entrance
- on a node representing a part of a building (e.g. a shop filling only one half of it).

The data is always available completely to the renderer, but it is up to him which elements he takes and which he drops.

Note that Geofabrik shapefiles only contain a subset of the data, so take the pbf files from them, or use the Overpass API.